# How does yum work?

Tags: yum

After I installed Fedora 20 on my new computer, I could not use 'yum install' because I just got a long string of error messages.

I first posted this question on this site: "How can I get yum and the internet browser to work after fresh Fedora 20 installation" which gives the full details of the errors I got early on.

After nearly six weeks of frustration I finally found the answer in:

```
http://qandasys.info/fedora-19-unable-to-update-or-install-could-not-resolve-host/

Answer by Stramash November 4, 2013 at 2:24 pm

Resolved this by adding nameserver 8.8.8.8 above my router’s address in resolv.conf that was obtained by DHCP.
```

I had also asked, here: "I have to do this edit every time I log on, and I would like to make it permanent." and soon found an answer in:

https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/users/2011-August/403189.html

So I did this edit:

vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-p20p1

changing the line: `PEERDNS=yes` to `PEERDNS=no`

Although this all works, I am not sure why. What I would, please, like is to read a detailed description of what yum does to locate an installation package, the files associated with this process, and how they can be modified or configured if necessary, for instance as a flow chart or list.

Comment: Which is the error you have?

Comment: Instead of adding the extra DNS directly in resolv.conf, add it in Network Manager, as Network Manager generates your resolv.conf.

Comment: Exactly what does `resolve.conf` look like *before* you do that?

Comment: @goldilocks OP had already posted it [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120085/linux-fedora-20-how-do-i-deal-with-import-read-failed2) when trying to fix the problem with yum.

Comment: Downvoters, please take a moment to suggest how the Q can be improved.

Answer (score 6):

This is not a problem with yum it seems, but DNS resolution instead.

It seems that the DNS settings that you manually add to /etc/resolv.conf are overwritten every time you boot your machine or renew network connection by Network Manager.

A good way to find out is to check the first lines of the resolv.conf file. If you see something like "this file was generated automatically.." then it is likely that you can't modify this file permanently.

If you are using DCHP to get IP settings, you should check your router settings and confirm that it provides a DNS server ( it depends on router model, search on google)
NOTE: if you can't control your DNS settings in router, you can do semi-automatic configuration in Network Manager ( see Fedora's [doc](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sec-Connecting_to_a_Network_Automatically.html))

If you are using static IP, go to Network Manager settings to define one.

Here the Fedora's doc [chapter](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sec-Configuring_IPv4_Settings.html)

Comment: +1 If your router does provide DNS, or has an external address that does (it should), it will tell the DHCP client that and the DHCP client will write that address into resolve.conf, I believe.  Kind of strange this does not happen.

Comment: This can be controlled in dhclient.conf. See entry:
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
        domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search,  
But I don't think Harry touched this?

Comment: The suggestions, for which I am grateful, all need a deeper understanding of the system than I have, hence the final paragraph of my question.

Comment: network-manager takes precedence on network-scripts as far as I know. I would suggest that you revert any change you have made to the device network scripts and follow my advice. If you are unfamiliar with Linux, you should use network-manager (see link in answer) to configure your network settings. Again you are describing a DNS resolution issue, not a yum related problem.

Comment: Regarding @rMistero's comments, thanks for them, Ok, I realise that yum is not the basic problem, but it was at the start of the process that leads to its revelation. I'm sorry, but you take too much for granted in what you expect me to understand: I don't (yet) know what network-manager and network-scripts are, nor what role they play.

Comment: @Harry, I don't assume that you know network-manager this is why I gave you the links to the doc on how to use it. If you are interested in understanding how network-manager works in the backend, you will find plenty of answers on the internet.